# opencv xcode 9 Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, opencv

[Error message from Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxfl4.png)

I need to use ximgproc module from OpenCV_contrib into my Xcode project. When I run the project I have an error like above.

```
Xcode 9.1 (9B55)
Target: iOS 11
OpenCV -> https://github.com/opencv/opencv
OpenCV_Contrib -> https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib
```

I have connected modules from these two libraries into one opencv2.framework .

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info ios/opencv2.framework/opencv2 
Architectures in the fat file: ios/opencv2.framework/opencv2 are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```

Architectures are fine.

Below Xcode project settings:

[Xcode configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYyzb.png)

I am stuck. I was trying everything.

I was trying everything according to:

http://ioscake.com/how-to-compile-opencv-for-ios7-arm64.html
https://www.extendi.it/blog/2015/5/22/46-how-to-add-opencv-2-4-11-in-your-ios-project -> I added also extra  libraries to the project:

```
Accelerate
AssetsLibrary
AVFoundation
CoreGraphics
CoreImage
CoreMedia
CoreVideo
QuartzCore
UIKit
Foundation
```

and

```
libc++.dylib
```

Has anyone idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried setting "Build Active Architecture Only" to yes? I usually find that helps when I'm getting errors like this.